# How to sort complex multidimensional array

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

i need to sort an array like this in function of the price:

```
Array
(
    [SJ] => Array
        (
            [desc] => Junior Suite
            [solutions] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [code] => BB
                            [desc] => Bed and Breakfast
                            [price] => 607.08
                            [status] => OK
                            [policy] => 1
                            [currency] => EU
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [code] => BB
                            [desc] => Bed and Breakfast
                            [price] => 700.80
                            [status] => OK
                            [policy] => 1
                            [currency] => EU
                        )

                )

        )

    [MZ] => Array
        (
            [desc] => Doble Deluxe con hidromasaje
            [solutions] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [code] => BB
                            [desc] => Bed and Breakfast
                            [price] => 518.40
                            [status] => OK
                            [policy] => 1
                            [currency] => EU
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Can someone give me the right way to do that? :)

**EXPECTED RESULT**

```
Array
(
    [MZ] => Array
        (
            [desc] => Doble Deluxe con hidromasaje
            [solutions] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [code] => BB
                            [desc] => Bed and Breakfast
                            [price] => 518.40
                            [status] => OK
                            [policy] => 1
                            [currency] => EU
                        )

                )

        )
    [SJ] => Array
        (
            [desc] => Junior Suite
            [solutions] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [code] => BB
                            [desc] => Bed and Breakfast
                            [price] => 607.08
                            [status] => OK
                            [policy] => 1
                            [currency] => EU
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [code] => BB
                            [desc] => Bed and Breakfast
                            [price] => 700.80
                            [status] => OK
                            [policy] => 1
                            [currency] => EU
                        )

                )

        )
)
```

What i need is to order that array in function of price. 
So if i have many solutions, i need to take the one that have minor price

Comment: **1)** What have you tried ? **2)** What's the expected output ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the PHP function `usort` like this:

```
function sortInnerPrice($a, $b) {
    if ($a['price'] == $b['price']) {
        return 0;
    }

    return ($a['price'] < $b['price']) ? -1 : 1;
}

// First sort the inner prices
foreach ($test as $key => $val) {
    usort($test[$key]['solutions'], 'sortInnerPrice');
}

function cmp($a, $b)
{
    $aPrice = $a['solutions'][0]['price'];
    $bPrice = $b['solutions'][0]['price'];
    if ($aPrice == $bPrice) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($aPrice < $bPrice) ? -1 : 1;
}

// Then sort by lowest solution price
usort($yourArray, "cmp");
```

`usort` is a PHP function that allows you to sort an array based on whatever you want. You create a function that will return 0 if they are the same, -1 if you want $a before $b, and 1 if you want $a after $b.

Comment: sorry, that was my mistake.. i have many solutions.. in that example there is only one.. but generally there are many solutions..

Comment: how do you want it sorted. By the average of solutions? the lowest solution? highest solution?

Comment: @JackTurky You'll probably have to first sort the solution prices separately then sort the outer objects by the lowest solution

Answer (score 0):

Try to make another array containing all the prices and then use [array_multisort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) for it